# rPi invoking OOMKiller when there is so much memory free

Tags: linux, memory

Whenever I'm doing intensive file operations, or just now and then, I have my OOMKiller invoked and something killed. However, I seem to have a lot of free memory when this happens:

```
[nitz@saturn ~]$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7Gi       123Mi       5.5Gi       0.0Ki       2.1Gi       7.5Gi
Swap:          2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

I tried moving my workloads (e.g. Deluge) to Docker, it seems they're not even approaching their limits:

```
CONTAINER ID   NAME                             CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O         PIDS
e43658667cb1   docker-compose-rhasspy-1         10.06%    173.9MiB / 1GiB     16.98%    4.96kB / 222B     295MB / 16.4kB    36
50f77474bf8d   docker-compose-caddy-1           0.05%     7.75MiB / 50MiB     15.50%    23.2kB / 31.8kB   39.1MB / 16.4kB   10
5a63ea5eb900   docker-compose-homeassistant-1   79.50%    73.24MiB / 1GiB     7.15%     31.6kB / 9.6kB    127MB / 1.43MB    20
c07d0922fb82   docker-compose-wireguard-1       0.22%     15.16MiB / 150MiB   10.11%    6.41kB / 164B     66.5MB / 434kB    17
836e97c7cbdc   docker-compose-zwavejs-1         1.73%     68.68MiB / 150MiB   45.79%    5.37kB / 0B       129MB / 8.19kB    11
e2abf6de1673   docker-compose-deluge-1          33.04%    104.7MiB / 4GiB     2.56%     50.8MB / 1.35MB   84.2MB / 8.34MB   12
```

I [attached some stack traces](https://pastebin.com/tH6e59J1) of OOMKiller, in case it indicates what's wrong.

Maybe relevant excerpt:

```
[  571.399130] Node 0 active_anon:772kB inactive_anon:69068kB active_file:537768kB inactive_file:1464348kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):8kB mapped:125152kB dirty:4036kB writeback:80kB shmem:1048kB writeback_tmp:0kB kernel_stack:2684kB pagetables:3812kB sec_pagetables:0kB all_unreclaimable? no
[  571.399155] DMA free:522564kB boost:0kB min:3140kB low:3924kB high:4708kB reserved_highatomic:4096KB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:272kB inactive_file:408kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:786432kB managed:626980kB mlocked:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:172kB local_pcp:128kB free_cma:516536kB
[  571.399181] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 7283 7283
[  571.399203] DMA: 394*4kB (UEH) 150*8kB (UEHC) 105*16kB (UEHC) 47*32kB (UEHC) 5*64kB (HC) 4*128kB (HC) 3*256kB (C) 4*512kB (C) 3*1024kB (C) 3*2048kB (C) 123*4096kB (C) = 522632kB
[  571.399284] 500804 total pagecache pages
[  571.399292] 0 pages in swap cache
[  571.399300] Free swap  = 2097148kB
[  571.399306] Total swap = 2097148kB
[  571.399313] 2061056 pages RAM
[  571.399320] 1864448 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[  571.399326] 39863 pages reserved
[  571.399336] 131072 pages cma reserved
```

What is going on? Is this some kernel-specific memory I'm running out of?

Things I tried:

1. Allocating swap: Seems to be unused
2. Moving Deluge to Docker, setting an explicit memory limit on all Docker whose sum is lower than the rPi's RAM total (7.7Gi)
3. Scouring the OOMKiller logs.

**Specs**: rPi 4, Arch Linux for ARM (ALARM), updated regularly.

### More dumps

- [`/etc/systemd/system.conf`](https://pastebin.com/pKChx359)
- There are no `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/*.conf` files.
- [`/etc/systemd/system/docker-compose.service`](https://pastebin.com/QjcT46hG).

Comment: The problem is not necessariy about how much memory you have, but about how much memory the application that triggered the OOM killer was trying to allocate at that time. Try to see if the logs include memory allocation problems.

Comment: it's still miss how much memory you wanted to request at this point I agree

Comment: It seems to me like there is 5GB of memory free. I think it is unlikely that something is trying to allocate 5GB. I uploaded a new pastebin that might help: https://pastebin.com/tH6e59J1

Comment: I am not familiar with the OOM killer. Does anyone know for sure whether the memory information shown here is before of after the kill? I suggest to track the development of this value `grep '^MemAvailable:' /proc/meminfo` (at least ten times per second) and check that development after an OOM kill.

Comment: Can you share your  `/etc/systemd/system.conf` file? , + the relevant part of the `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/*.conf` files?

Comment: Hint: "SwapUsedLimit=

Sets the limit for memory and swap usage on the system before systemd-oomd will take action. If the fraction of memory used and the fraction of swap used on the system are both more than what is defined here, systemd-oomd will act on eligible descendant control groups with swap usage greater than 5% of total swap, starting from the ones with the highest swap usage. Which control groups are monitored and what action gets taken depends on what the unit has configured for ManagedOOMSwap= Takes a value specified in percent...."
https://man.archlinux.org/man/oomd.conf.5.en

Comment: @K-att- added to question

Comment: Thank you. I have no idea. Maybe increase the TasksMax to 50%...

Comment: Can you try to change the DefaultTaskmax from 15% to 60%?
Hint: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/defaulttasksmax-systemd-v228-phani-arava